# Issue with toggling ListBox selected item using switch-case in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a ListBox control (listBox2) in my C# Windows Forms application, and I am trying to toggle the selected item between "in time render yes" and "in time render no" using a switch-case statement. However, the selected item does not change when executing the code.

Here is the code snippet I am using:

```
switch (listBox2.SelectedItem)
{
    case "in time render     yes":
        listBox2.SelectedItem = "in time render     no";
        break;
    case "in time render     no":
        listBox2.SelectedItem = "in time render     yes";
        break;
    default:
        // Handle other initial values if needed
        break;
}
```

I have verified that the listBox2.SelectedItem initially has either "in time render yes" or "in time render no" as the selected item. However, the code does not seem to update the selected item accordingly.

Can anyone help me identify the issue with this code? Is there a better approach to toggle the selected item of a ListBox control?

Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use a checkbox? Beside that, the spaces between the word _render_ and _no/yes_ are exactly as the ones present in your code? Do you have used the debugger to check what value is assigned to SelectedItem when this code hits the switch statement?

Comment: The value of the SelectedItem must be a value contained in the Items source.

Comment: If you want to *modify* an item in a ListBox then you have to remove the item and add it again, now with the modified text.

Comment: @HansPassant but if i do this the item would be added in the last index of listbox.

Comment: In which event do you run this code?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection.insert?view=windowsdesktop-7.0

Comment: Please @user21947388 could you explain what items are present in your listbox and how do you add them? Are you just trying to flip the current selected item to another item in the listbox and viceversa?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to remove and add the item modified as someone suggested before, to modify the text..

```
listBox.Items[listBox.SelectedIndex] = "new text for the item";
```

Weird because your code works for me.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    listBox2.Items.Add("in time render     yes");
    listBox2.Items.Add("in time render     no");
    listBox2.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (listBox2.SelectedItem)
    {
        case "in time render     yes":
            listBox2.SelectedItem = "in time render     no";
            break;
        case "in time render     no":
            listBox2.SelectedItem = "in time render     yes";
            break;
        default:
            // Handle other initial values if needed
            break;
    }
}
```

This works too..

```
private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch (listBox2.SelectedIndex)
    {
        case 0:
            listBox2.SelectedItem = listBox2.Items[1];
            break;
        case 1:
            listBox2.SelectedItem = listBox2.Items[0];
            break;
        default:
            // Handle other initial values if needed
            break;
    }
}
```

If you want to use a ListBox, you can do it. But there are better options like a CheckBox or a ComboBox for a Binary option that requires a toggle.

With a CheckBox, to make a toggle is this easy

```
private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkBox.Checked = !checkBox.Checked;
}
```

Comment: This is a winforms question, not for wpf

Comment: @Steve my bad, I'll change the little details